# Fade in hidden element from bottom to top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a page where I have an section `main-section` that with the top bar takes 100% height of the screen.
Since my `top-bar` is `77px` high it is set up like this in css:

```
#app {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url('/img/cover.png');
  background-size: cover;
}

#main-section {
  position: absolute;
  top: 77px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#magazine-detail {
  position: absolute;
  top: 77px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

This is how it looks in the html:

```
<div id="app">

    @section('topBar')
      @include('customer.layouts.partials.top-bar')
    @show

    <div id="main-section">
      @section('header')
        @include('customer.layouts.partials.header')
      @show

      @section('carousel')
        @include('customer.layouts.partials.carousel')
      @show
    </div>

    <div id="magazine-detail">
      @section('magazine-detail')
        @include('customer.layouts.partials.magazine-detail')
      @show
    </div>

    <div class="large-10 large-centered columns content">
      @yield('content')
    </div>
  </div>
```

Initially the `main-section` is visible and `magazine-detail` is hidden. On click of a button magazine-detail takes up the space of main section. I did that with fadeIn, fadeOut of each of the sections like this in my js. file:

```
$('#magazine-detail').fadeIn(2000);
$('#main-section').fadeOut(2000);
```

I wonder how can I make it fadeIn, so that it appears that it comes from bottom to top, like a drawer kind of effect?

Comment: Pretty sure `@section('topBar')` is not valid HTML... Also, look at the [Effects section of the jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/sliding/) for other effects you can use.

Comment: It is a larvel blade template engine, just wanted to show to sections, since I thought there was no need for full html

Answer (score 0):

You can use jqueryui "drop" effect, here is a fiddle i made using docs (api.jqueryui.com/drop-effect/)

https://jsfiddle.net/6L0gkvhq/1/

```
    $('#button').click(function() {
      $("#toggle").toggle("drop", {direction: "down"});
      $("#main").toggle("fade");
    });
```

Or use api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: When I use drop, some parts of the main-section don't get hidden, so then I have both visible.

Comment: was this what you wanted to achieve visually?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, animating `clip` may be your best bet:

**CSS:**

```
#magazine-detail {
  position: absolute;
  top: 77px;
  display: none;
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var $md = $('#magazine-detail');

    $md.show();
    $('#main-section').fadeOut(2000);
    $({val: $md.height()}).animate(
    {val: 0},
    {
        duration: 2000,
        step: function (now) {
        $md.css('clip', 
                'rect(' + now + 'px, ' + $md.width() + 'px, ' + $md.height() + 'px, 0px)'
               );
      } 
    }
  );
```

**Snippet:**

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  var $md = $('#magazine-detail');

  $md.show();
  $('#main-section').fadeOut(2000);
  $({val: $md.height()}).animate(
   {val: 0},
    {
     duration: 2000,
     step: function (now) {
     $md.css('clip', 
             'rect(' + now + 'px, ' + $md.width() + 'px, ' + $md.height() + 'px, 0px)'
            );
    } 
   }
  );
});
```

```css
div {
  font: 16px arial;
  width: 600px;
}

#main-section {
  position: absolute;
  top: 77px;
}

#magazine-detail {
  position: absolute;
  top: 77px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>
  Show detail
</button>
<div id="main-section">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.<br>
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/100/">
</div>

<div id="magazine-detail">
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/100/"><br>
Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem.

</div>
```